# Rounding and adding a border to a UIImage - Not UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uibezierpath, cgrect

I have an extension that rounds the corners of a UIImage. This extension works great. I'd also like to add a stroke/border to the image.

The reason I'm not doing all of this on a UIImageView is because the scaling/aspect ratio of the images changes, so it needs to round & stroke the image, and not the imageView itself.

```
extension UIImage{
    var roundedImage: UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: self.size)

        let border = CAShapeLayer()
        border.path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)
        border.lineWidth = 10
        border.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor


        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 1)
        UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect,
            cornerRadius: 40
            ).addClip()
        self.draw(in: rect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    }
}
```

I made progress by adding the `CAShapeLayer()` to add the red stroke. Just can't figure out how to add it to the actual path of `roundedImage`. Or if this is even the right approach.

**How can I create a UIImage extension to both round the corners and add a border/stroke?**

Comment: can you explain visually ? what you want and what you are getting ?

Comment: If you have UIImageView set to .aspectFit, you should see the entire image regardless of size. Manipulating UIImage itself is an odd approach. What is your overall goal for the rounded images? Displaying them in a collection view with varying height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Extension

```
 extension UIImage { 
  var rounded: UIImage? { 
     let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
     defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() } 
     let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 40)
     bezierPath.addClip() 
     bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
     draw(in: rect)
     guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil } 
     context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor) 
     bezierPath.lineWidth = 10 
     bezierPath.stroke() 
     return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() }
     }
```

Comment: `origin: .zero` btw you should call UIGraphicsEndImageContext() after getting your image from context `defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }`

Comment: Btw you should use scale equal to zero and return an optional UIImage. I would also name it `rounded` image is redundant

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you for for your suggestion to make it a better solution

Comment: Note that this would clip the red line at the edges as well

Comment: You should keep a hold of your bezier path, set its lineWidth to 10 and then stroke it instead of the rect

Comment: `extension UIImage {
 var rounded: UIImage? {
 let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
 defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
 let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 40)
 bezierPath.addClip()
 bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
        draw(in: rect)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
        bezierPath.stroke()
       return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}`